# How do I make linker arguments use variables that depend on the target in a makefile?

Tags: makefile

I have the following in my Makefile

`LDFLAGS += -Wl,-Map=test.map`

Which writes some extended info about the binary to `test.map`.

However these linker options are used for many targets and I would like the name of the actual target to be inserted for "test". Otherwise the map file will constantly be overwritten.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$@` to get the name of the target:

```
LDFLAGS += -W1, -Map=$@.map
```

Keep in mind when you do this kind of thing that there's a difference between defining variables with `=` or `:=` (more details here [1](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Flavors.html#Flavors)).

[1]: [The Two Flavors of Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Flavors.html#Flavors)